# Why R2 Score is zero in LightGBM?

Tags: python, lightgbm

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import lightgbm
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score,mean_squared_error as MSE
dataset = pd.read_excel("Prali Marble.xlsx")
X = dataset.iloc[:,2].values.reshape((-1, 1))
Y = dataset.iloc[:,3].values

from lightgbm import LGBMRegressor
lgb_r = LGBMRegressor()
lgb_r.fit(X,Y)
y_pred = lgb_r.predict(X)
print("LGBM R2_SCORE:", r2_score(Y, lgb_r.predict(X)))
```

R2 score is given **ZERO**, so why was the zero value obtained in LGBMRegressor?
I did not split my data train_test because my dataset small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example is not fully reproducible since the content of `"Prali Marble.xlsx"` is not included.

However, I can reproduce a 0.0 R<sup>2</sup> with the following code that I think closely matches your example. Similar to your code, this trains a LightGBM regression model on a dataset with a single feature.

This code uses `lightgbm`  3.1.1 on Python 3.8.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score,mean_squared_error as MSE

X = pd.DataFrame({
    "feat1": np.append(np.repeat(0.5, 99), np.ones(1))
})
Y = np.random.random(100, )

lgb_r = lgb.LGBMRegressor()
lgb_r.fit(X,Y)

y_pred = lgb_r.predict(X)
print("LGBM R2_SCORE:", r2_score(Y, lgb_r.predict(X)))
```

> LGBM R2_SCORE: 0.0

In this case, the R<sup>2</sup> is 0 because the model is just predicting the mean of `Y`. You can see this by examining the structure of the model.

```py
lgb_r.booster_.trees_to_dataframe()
```

That will return a 1-row dataframe, which happens when LightGBM does not add any trees.

LightGBM has some parameters that are used to prevent overfitting. Two are relevant here:

- [`min_data_in_leaf`](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#min_data_in_leaf) (default=20)
- [`min_sum_hessian_in_leaf`](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#min_sum_hessian_in_leaf) (default=0.001)

You can tell LightGBM to ignore these overfitting protections by setting these parameters to 0.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

X = pd.DataFrame({
    "feat1": np.append(np.repeat(0.5, 99), np.ones(1))
})
Y = np.random.random(100, )

lgb_r = lgb.LGBMRegressor(
    min_data_in_leaf=0,
    min_sum_hessian_in_leaf=0.0
)
lgb_r.fit(X,Y)

y_pred = lgb_r.predict(X)
print("LGBM R2_SCORE:", r2_score(Y, lgb_r.predict(X)))
```

Comment: Hi @JamesLamb, thank you man!! I have tried and I got R2_score : 0.78 many thanks

Comment: Great, glad it helped!