# Why LightGBM Python-package gives bad prediction using for regression task?

Tags: python, regression, lightgbm

I have a sample time-series dataset (23, 208), which is a pivot table count for 24hrs count for some users; I was experimenting with different regressors from sklearn which work fine (except for [SGDRegressor()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html)), but this [LightGBM Python-package](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-Intro.html#prediction) gives me very linear prediction as follows:

[image: img]
my tried code:

```py
import pandas as pd
dff = pd.read_csv('ex_data2.csv',sep=',')
dff.set_index("timestamp",inplace=True)
print(dff.shape)


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
trainingSetf, testSetf = train_test_split(dff,
                                        #target_attribute, 
                                        test_size=0.2,
                                        random_state=42,
                                        #stratify=y,
                                        shuffle=False)


import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor

username = 'MMC_HEC_LVP' # select one column for plotting & check regression performance
user_list = []

for column in dff.columns:
  user_list.append(column)


index = user_list.index(username)

X_trainf = trainingSetf.iloc[:,:].values
y_trainf = trainingSetf.iloc[:,:].values

X_testf = testSetf.iloc[:,:].values
y_testf = testSetf.iloc[:,:].values
test_set_copy = y_testf.copy()

model_LGBMRegressor = MultiOutputRegressor(lgb.LGBMRegressor()).fit(X_trainf, y_trainf)
pred_LGBMRegressor = model_LGBMRegressor.predict(X_testf)

test_set_copy[:,[index]] = pred_LGBMRegressor[:,[index]]

#plot the results for selected user/column 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("fivethirtyeight")

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))

plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Values")
plt.title(f"{username} Plot")

plt.plot(trainingSetf.iloc[:,[index]],label='trainingSet')
plt.plot(testSetf.iloc[:,[index]],"--",label='testSet')
plt.plot(test_set_copy[:,[index]],'b--',label='RF_predict')
plt.legend()
```

So what I am missing is if I use default (hyper-)parameters?

Comment: I started to answer this tonight, but cannot reproduce the results in your post. The dataset you link to has timestamps from 2022-01-16  to 2022-02-07, but the data in the plot you've provided seems to show dates from some other range involving the month of May (not sure how to interpret them). If you can share the EXACT data used for your post (and preferably code to generate a dataset, instead of a link too a Google Drive file that you could remove at any time), I'd be happy to provide an answer.

Comment: @JamesLamb, thanks for your comment. As you said, the plot in the above post belongs to another range of collected data for May. So I provided you with a *similar*  dataset for another time range you mentioned, and there is no problem as long as it resolves the issues\problem. Please feel free to offer your answer.
Looking forward to understanding the *linear prediction* output of this package with default config.

Comment: BTW I updated the pic for that time range and a certain column (`MMC_HEC_LVP`) in the above post.

Comment: @JamesLamb Any updates for this or do you wanna bounty? I'm ok.

Comment: I will try to answer when I can. It may be a week or more. Maybe someone else will be able to answer your question before then.

Comment: @JamesLamb waiting for your feedback/answer possibly.

Comment: Running a simplified version of the provided code (removing `MultiOutputRegressor`), I saw LightGBM produce the warning `There are no meaningful features, as all feature values are constant.`. I believe this is a bug in LightGBM, for very small datasets. I've opened [microsoft/LightGBM#5081](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/5081) documenting it For your dataset, I recommend not using LightGBM. If you continue with LightGBM, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66715748/why-r2-score-is-zero-in-lightgbm/66728185#66728185) for advice on working with small datasets.

Comment: I just posted an answer...found in the linked LightGBM discussion that passing `min_data_in_leaf=1` will resolve this issue for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

Your dataset has a very small number of rows, and LightGBM's parameters have default values set to provide good performance on medium-sized datasets.

Set the following parameters to force LightGBM to fit to the provided data.

- [`min_data_in_bin`](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#min_data_in_bin) = 1
- [`min_data_in_leaf`](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#min_data_in_leaf) = 1

### Long Answer

Before training, LightGBM does some pre-processing on the input data.

For example:

- bundling sparse features
- binning continuous features into histograms
- dropping features which are guaranteed to be uninformative (for example, features which are constant)

The result of that preprocessing is a LightGBM `Dataset` object, and running that preprocessing is called `Dataset` "construction". LightGBM performs boosting on this `Dataset` object, not raw data like `numpy` arrays or `pandas` data frames.

To speed up construction and prevent overfitting during training, LightGBM provides ability to the prevent creation of histogram bins that are too small (`min_data_in_bin`) or splits that produce leaf nodes which match too few records (`min_data_in_leaf`).

Setting those parameters to very low values may be required to train on small datasets.

I created the following [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), using Python 3.8.12, `lightgbm==3.3.2`, `numpy==1.22.2`, and `scikit-learn==1.0.2` demonstrating this behavior.

```py
from lightgbm import LGBMRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

# 20-row input data
X, y = make_regression(
    n_samples=20,
    n_informative=5,
    n_features=5,
    random_state=708
)

# training produces 0 trees, and predicts mean(y)
reg = LGBMRegressor(
    num_boost_round=20,
    verbosity=0
)
reg.fit(X, y)
print(f"r2 (defaults): {r2_score(y, reg.predict(X))}")
# 0.000

# training fits and predicts well
reg = LGBMRegressor(
    min_data_in_bin=1,
    min_data_in_leaf=1,
    num_boost_round=20,
    verbosity=0
)
reg.fit(X, y)
print(f"r2 (small min_data): {r2_score(y, reg.predict(X))}")
# 0.985
```

If you use `LGBMRegressor(min_data_in_bin=1, min_data_in_leaf=1)` in the code in the original post, you'll see predictions that better fit to the provided data.

Comment: that configuration solved the problem! many thanks!

Comment: May I ask you kindly check this [**bounty** question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/121124/69263) expires **tomorrow**. It could be a similar issue with `RandomForestRegressor()` configuration of hyper-parameters

Answer (score 0):

In this way the model is overfitted!
If you do a random split after creating the dataset and evaluate the model on the test dataset, you will notice that the performance is essentially the same or worse (as in this example).

```py
# SETUP
# =============================================================

from lightgbm import LGBMRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


X, y = make_regression(
    n_samples=200, n_informative=10, n_features=40, random_state=123
)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42
)

# =============================================================
# TEST 1
reg = LGBMRegressor(num_boost_round=20, verbosity=0)
reg.fit(X, y)
print(f"r2 (defaults): {r2_score(y, reg.predict(X))}")
# 0.815


reg = LGBMRegressor(
    min_data_in_bin=1, min_data_in_leaf=1, num_boost_round=20, verbosity=0
)
reg.fit(X, y)
print(f"r2 (small min_data): {r2_score(y, reg.predict(X))}")
# 0.974


# =============================================================
# TEST 2
reg = LGBMRegressor(num_boost_round=20, verbosity=0)

reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(f"r2 (defaults): {r2_score(y_train, reg.predict(X_train))}")
# 0.759


reg = LGBMRegressor(
    min_data_in_bin=1, min_data_in_leaf=1, num_boost_round=20, verbosity=0
)
reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(f"r2 (small min_data): {r2_score(y_test, reg.predict(X_test))}")
# 0.219
```

Comment: I provided the dataset in the post; you can check if the model is going to be overfitted. When I plot the values over time by configuration @James offered, LGBM prediction had an acceptable generalization gap with actual values as far as I remember. I don't see any problem with *"If you do a random spit after creating the dataset and evaluate the model on the test dataset"* when you said. What do you offer instead?